# Simple bash script for testing read/write to a file until stopped manually?

Tags: bash

I need to test read/write access to disk until I manually terminate my test.

Right now I have this:

```
filename='test.txt'
touch $filename
count=0
while [ 1 ]; 
do 
    echo "test-content-$count" > $filename
    cat $filename
     ((count=count+1))
    test $? -gt 128 && break;
done
```

but was wondering if there is a better *one liner* approach to this that does the same?

And also if it can retry after a second or two in case connection is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liners don't generally does *not* really guarantee the code that is readable and efficient in performance.

What you can improve upon your logic is to just open the file for appending and see if its successful and fail on the first instance when you were not able to open the file

```
while :; do
    if ! ( [ -e "$filename" ] && >> "$filename" ); then
        printf '%s\n' "$?"; break
    fi
done
```

The above code would exit out at the first instance when the file can't be opened, i.e. when `>> "$filename"` returns a non-zero exit code and the inversion of the exit code using `!` will assert the `if` condition to be true. At this point you can just break out of the loop and print the error code returned.

To retry the write again, after sometime once it fails,  remove the `break` and add a `continue`

```
while :; do
    if ! ( [ -e "$filename" ] && >> "$filename" ); then
        printf '%s\n' "$?"; sleep 10
        continue
    fi
done
```